# Update angular 5 to 6+ ngx-bootstrap error

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, rxjs, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to update my application from angular 5 to angular 6+.
After updating a lot of packages I have this error and I'm stuck on that.

```
ERROR in chunk app [entry]
app.bundle.js
/home/sonyde/Documents/project/extranet/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/esm5/ngx-bootstrap.js dc21e88b40837b73971f9f5c6a9b4b40
Unexpected token (467:27)
|     function BsLocaleService() {
|         this._defaultLocale = 'en';
|         this._locale = new !(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'rxjs'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())(this._defaultLocale);
|         this._localeChange = this._locale.asObservable();
|     }

ERROR in vendor.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: operator (!) [./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:4463,36][vendor.bundle.js:5560,36]
```

I updated angular (5.2 to 6.1), webpack (3.12.0 to 4.19.0) and rxjs (5.5.2 to 6.0.0) versions.
I don't think the error comes from uglifyjs because we already tried to remove it and the error is still there, in the console.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

My packages :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/cli": "6",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
    "@epegzz/sass-vars-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "6.2.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "ts2.0",
    "@types/node": "6.0.45",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "2.1.3",
    "@types/swiper": "^3.4.3",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.12.1",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.16",
    "codelyzer": "^3.0.1",
    "common-models": "2.3.2",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "^1.3.4",
    "cookieconsent": "3.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "d3-ng2-service": "^2.2.0",
    "deep-extend": "0.4.1",
    "dynamic-i18n": "^1.0.5",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "flat": "^4.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "html-webpack-exclude-assets-plugin": "^0.0.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "htmllint": "^0.6.0",
    "htmllint-cli": "^0.0.6",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "1.4.4",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "mixgen": "1.1.7",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "moment-range": "^3.0.3",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "6.1.0",
    "ng2-select-compat": "1.3.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "4.3.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "node-sass-json-importer": "^3.0.2",
    "parallel-webpack": "3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.2.228",
    "pretty-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "release-it": "^10.0.0",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.8",
    "simple-progress-webpack-plugin-with-prefix": "^1.1.1",
    "sourcemapped-stacktrace": "^1.1.11",
    "string-replace-loader": "2.3.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "sweetalert2": "6.6.3",
    "swiper": "^3.4.2",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.12",
    "tslib": "1.10.0",
    "tslint": "5.20.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.9.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.2",
    "webpack": "4.19.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.8.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.8.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.10",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass directly from the version 5 to 7?

Comment: ngx-bootstrap 3.3.0 is 2 years old, try to use 4.0.0 or 4.3.0 to see, 4.x should work with angular 6 or 7

Comment: Tried to update ngx-bootstrap to 4.3.0 like their github suggests, but I still get the same error.
Updated the original post